# Is Java 1.6 compatible with Neo4j?

Tags: java, neo4j

I am using JDK 6, and my present database is MySQL 5.5.27.
As my data is in a tree structure I want to go for a graph database. I have a need for both in-memory and file system based datastore.

Is Neo4j compatible with Java 1.6? On their website and tutorial links, they have stated Java 7 as the requirement.

Comment: "On their website and tutorial links, they have stated java 7 as the requirement." - I think that answers your question. Why would you not trust neo4j's own documentation on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the neo4j document it is written that:

> Neo4j likes Java 1.6 JVMs and running in server mode so consider upgrading to that if you haven’t yet (or at least give the -server flag).

Details can be found [here in neo4j docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/performance-guide.html).

So, this seems that it is compatible with jdk1.6.

Comment: (The link points to a page in the "stable" version of neo4j ... and it no longer mentions Java 6.)

Answer (score 2):

According to the neo4j website as of now, the oldest downloadable version of the community edition is 1.9.9, and the documentation for [1.9.9](http://neo4j.com/docs/1.9.9/deployment-requirements.html) says that Oracle Java 7 is a prerequisite.

It may be possible to get older versions (e.g. a 2013 version) but you would be advised to contact Neo4j (the company) to find out a reliable place to get them.

Comment: as far as I remember Neo4j 1.9.x works on JDK 6, but wasn't officially supported for that. Anything >= 2.0 requires at least JDK 7.